# Mule 3.3.0 - ajax connector and jersey resource on same domain

Tags: ajax, http, post, jersey, mule

I setup a ajax server in mule that hosts a webpage:

```
<ajax:connector name="ajaxServer" serverUrl="http://0.0.0.0:8090/test" resourceBase="${app.home}/docroot">
```

On the webpage, I want to be able to upload a file using http post to a jersey resource I have setup:

```
<flow name="ModuleUploadFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:8090/test/jersey" connectorref="HttpConnector"/>
    <jersey:resources>
        ...
    </jersey:resources>
</flow>
```

The problem is that the ajax server binds to the port specified so my inbound http endpoint needs to be on a different port (domain). Is there a way to do the POST to a service on a different domain? I tried setting up an http proxy but I get the same port bound error. Any suggestions would help. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think this is possible but I would love to be proven wrong.